# Spring decorator with constructor injection with xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, decorator

I am using the decorator patter in my application and would like to configure it in xml spring configuration.

Lets say I have a class `someService` and a decorator called `someServiceDecorator`. Both services have multiple dependencies.

I tried this:

`<beans:bean id="someService" autowire="constructor" class="com.my.someService" />
<beans:bean id="someServiceDecorator" autowire="constructor" primary="true" class="com.my.someServiceDecorator" />`

Without success. I think it is strange I can't find any examples of the decorator pattern for spring with xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just tried this and this worked.

```
<beans:bean id="someServiceDecorator" autowire="constructor" class="com.my.someServiceDecorator">
    <constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean autowire="constructor" class="com.my.someService" />
    </constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```